# Prevent Windows Screen Locking using SessionSwitch event

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I am just wondering if it is possible to stop a windows workstation from locking using the SessionSwitch event in a Windows Form.

I am working on a (very simple) time and attendance system, and I want to prevent a user locking their screen unless they have set their status to away/lunch.

Current code is like this.

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
      SystemEvents.SessionSwitch += new SessionSwitchEventHandler(SystemEvents_SessionSwitch);
    }

void SystemEvents_SessionSwitch(object sender, SessionSwitchEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Reason == SessionSwitchReason.SessionLock)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Logout reason " + e.Reason);
            // Check if status is valid for logout, if not then prevent lock
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to prevent the screen locking from within a windows form? Or should I look for a different solution?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can do this (ultimately, the user has to retain control). Can you not just set the status to Away automatically?

Comment: Hi Damien, if it is not possible (which certainly seems the case) then I will have to do something like this. There are about 4 or 5 valid reasons for logging off, and we want to track these reasons so we can track user efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can stop the user from locking the screen. But, even if you can, what good would it be? They can still go away without locking their screen, can't they?

To me, it comes across as if you need to attribute time to a valid category like Lunch, Work, Meeting, etc. If that's the case, you need to realize that you can't force the user to do it. But, you can incentivize the user to do so or punish the user for not doing so.

I might suggest, hooking up to relevant event (SessionSwitch, Applications.Idle) and using a heuristics to guess the category (say if computer is idle for more than 20 minutes then categorize it as Lunch break). Provide the user with the ability to change the categorization. This way folks who have 3 lunch breaks in their timesheet, might start setting the system with the correct category before leaving for a break.